# Delphi - Why can't I install my component in 64Bit?

Tags: delphi, components, 32bit-64bit

I programmed a custom-component and tried to install it in my Delphi 10.1 environment.

I only had a .Pas-file.

I went to:

Components - Install-Components, selected my Unit which is in a new folder on my desktop -> made a new package in the same directory -> hit finish

now when I open my packege in the IDE and set the platform to windows 64Bit I can compile but not install my component.

my component is derived from the TEdit-control, don't know if this is relevant.

in my requires list are the following:

```
dbrtl.dcp
rtl.dcp
vcl.dcp
vclactnband.dcp
vcldb.dcp
vclx.dcp
xmlrtl.dcp
```

I'd really like to use my component in 32Bit-applications as well as 64Bit applications.

Other VCL-Controls provided by the IDE have no problem compiling in a 64Bit application, but my component is greyed out when I set my project to 64Bit.

I'm on win8.1 64Bit.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/64-bit_Windows_Application_Development#Making_Your_Components_Available_at_Design_Time_and_Run_Time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IDE is a 32 bit process. Therefore you can only install 32 bit packages. However, the runtime, 64 bit programs can use your component. Either by linking it directly, or by runtime packages. In the latter case, you would need to supply a 64 bit runtime package.

This is covered in some detail by the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/64-bit_Windows_Application_Development#Considerations_for_64-bit_Applications

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Do what? There are a number of steps. First of all get the 32 bit design time package installed. First thing for you to do is prove that you can make everything work for 32 bit. After that it's easy.

Comment: 32Bit worked with no issue. After that I switched to 64bit for my .bpl and said Compile and create.

now when I tried components->install component->same unit, same package. I got an error, application is not a valid win32 application.

Comment: I still don't know how you link, whether you use runtime packages or not. Steps are different. In any case, you do the same as for 32 bit, but with 64 bit modules. But no 64 bit design time package. Forget about installing anything more into the IDE. You only do that for the 32 hit design time package.

Comment: I don't know why but just now I am able to use my component in 64bit as well.

I'm still clueless about how it all works.

so, when I install a .pas as component it compiles and installs in 32bit, then I open my .bpl and compile and create it in 64bit and do what afterwards?

Comment: I think I answered the question, which was why you can't install a 64 bit design time package. I don't want to enter into a game of 20 questions in comments with such vague details.

Comment: You need to create 32-bit and 64-bit runtime packages for the component code, and a 32-bit design-time package to install the component into the IDE. DO NOT create a 64-bit design-time package.  The Form Designer works only with the 32-bit component.  When compiling a 64-bit project, it links to the 64-bit runtime package. This is explained in [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/64-bit_Windows_Application_Development#Considerations_for_64-bit_Applications).